# How to move Entry close to Label in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python and Tkinter, i wish to do exactly 
[image]

But my output now is:

[image]

I tried different ways but can't move the yellow labelled Entry box close to the search, and the Label `Dictionary:` is not same level as the text editor.

```
from ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import *

class Init(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root.title('Sample')
        root.geometry('700x300')
        MainFrame()
        DictionaryFrame()

class MainFrame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Textarea()

    def Textarea(self):
        self.txtareaframe = Frame(root)
        self.txtareaframe.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.txtareaframe)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.txtarea = Text(self.txtareaframe, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set, height=10, width=50)
        self.txtarea.pack()
        self.scroll.config(command=self.txtarea.yview)

class DictionaryFrame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionaryframe = Frame(root)
        self.dictionaryframe.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

        self.emptylbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='')  #This is just a empty space placeholder
        self.emptylbl.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=50)

        self.dictionarylbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='Dictionary: ')
        self.dictionarylbl.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="w")
        self.dictionarylist = Listbox(self.dictionaryframe)
        self.dictionarylist.grid(row=2, column=4)

        self.searchlbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='Search: ')
        self.searchlbl.grid(row=3, column=4,sticky="w")
        self.searchinput = Entry(self.dictionaryframe, width=25)
        self.searchinput.grid(row=3, column=5)

root = Tk()
Init()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your widgets are positioned at the right places. You only need to pass a few parameters, mostly `sticky` direction:

```
from tkinter import *

class Init(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root.title('Sample')
        root.geometry('700x300')
        MainFrame()
        DictionaryFrame()

class MainFrame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.txtareaframe = Frame(root)
        self.txtareaframe.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nesw") #1
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.txtareaframe)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.txtarea = Text(self.txtareaframe, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set, height=10, width=50)
        self.txtarea.pack(fill="both",expand=True) #2
        self.scroll.config(command=self.txtarea.yview)

class DictionaryFrame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionaryframe = Frame(root)
        self.dictionaryframe.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="w") #3

        self.emptylbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='')
        self.emptylbl.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=50)

        self.dictionarylbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='Dictionary: ')
        self.dictionarylbl.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="w")
        self.dictionarylist = Listbox(self.dictionaryframe)
        self.dictionarylist.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky="ew") #4

        self.searchlbl = Label(self.dictionaryframe, text='Search: ')
        self.searchlbl.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky="w")
        self.searchinput = Entry(self.dictionaryframe, width=25)
        self.searchinput.grid(row=3, column=5)

root = Tk()
Init()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't really understand `sticky="nesw"`, why when sticky in all direction (North, South, East, West), it will align with the text editor? I thought the sticky is to align something to which direction.

Comment: You will need it because apart from your `Text`  and `Scrollbar` widget, the container `self.txtareaframe` also needs to be able to expand.